# System.MethodAccessException: 'Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

In .NETCore, While running the application in `Program.cs` file at `CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();`

I'm getting the Exception

> "System.MethodAccessException: 'Attempt by method
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggerProviderConfigurationFactory.GetConfiguration(System.Type)'
>   to access method
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ProviderAliasUtilities.GetAlias(System.Type)'
>   failed.'"

in the Method

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

How to resolve this. I tried by uninstalling and Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore but  no use, Please see the screenshot of my Dependencies[image: dependies i added in Project]

Except theMicrosoft.Extension.Logging all the versions of dependcies are same. is there any problem that version difference. can someone help me to sort out this.

Comment: Is your project building successfully?

Comment: Yes. My project is building successfully

Comment: Why do you install `Microsoft.AspNetCore` instead of  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and why only the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` is 3.1.0 which should also be 2.2.0?

Answer (score 5):

The exception says the problem resides in 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggerProviderConfigurationFactory' (contained in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration assembly).

As Microsoft says here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.methodaccessexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

The MethodAccessException exception is thrown in situations such as the following:

- A private, protected, or internal method that would not be accessible from normal compiled code is accessed from partially trusted code by using reflection.
- The access level of a method in a class library has changed, and one or more assemblies that reference the library have not been recompiled.

Basically, you have a reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging '3.1.6', but another reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Logging version '2.2.0', and that assembly was surely compiled before Microsoft.Extensions.Logging '3.1.6'

All can be resolved modifying/adding an explicit Package Reference in your project:

Answer (score 4):

This problem occur when Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore@3.1 is added in a ASP.NET Core 2.1 project :

```
dotnet new web --name WebDemo --framework netcoreapp2.1 --target-framework-override net48
cd WebDemo
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 3.1.31
dotnet run
```

> `--target-framework-override net48` is to avoid to add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App) that include EF Core.

Then this error occurs :

```
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggerProviderConfigurationFactory.GetConfiguration(System.Type)' to access method 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ProviderAliasUtilities.GetAlias(System.Type)' failed.

at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggerProviderConfigurationFactory.GetConfiguration(Type providerType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggerProviderConfiguration`1..ctor(ILoggerProviderConfigurationFactory providerConfigurationFactory)
...
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
at WebDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in .\WebDemo\Program.cs:line 17
```

The WebHost can't load the loggin configuration... Why?

Ok, see the tree dependencies :

- [Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/2.1.7)

  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.1
  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.1
- [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.31](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.31)

  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.1.31

The dependency **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging** is present two times with two distinct versions. As the project don't specify explicitly a version, the highest version is chosen. So the project has this dependencies :

- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.1.31
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.1

If we refer to the exception's stack trace, we see that the problem comes from the package **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration** that use the method **ProviderAliasUtilities.GetAlias** of the package **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging**.

Problem... this method was in [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging version 2.*](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/ProviderAliasUtilities.cs#L14) was moved since the version 3.* to **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration** by [shared code](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/v3.1.14/src/Shared/src/ProviderAliasUtilities/ProviderAliasUtilities.cs).

Then **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration@2.*** isn't compatible with **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging@3.***, contrary to what the NuGet package information says :

- [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration/2.1.1)

  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 2.1.1)
  - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions (>= 2.1.1)

---

To resolve the error, you must explicitly add to the project the dependency **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration** at version 3.* :

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration --version 3.1.31
```

Comment: For me it seems only the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration` package was needed.

Comment: @Fred - I agree. I updated my answer to add explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I had to install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration` package (not the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` package).

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" Version="3.1.31" />
```

The version needs to be the same as your conflicting dependency, so if you use EF Core 3.2.31 you need to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration` 3.2.31 too.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is using dot net core version 2.2. Version mismatch in your package dependency cause this issue. Can you reinstall the correct version using following command line in Package Manager Console?

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging -Version 2.2.0
```

if you use .net core cli use the following command

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging --version 2.2.0
```

or directly edit the package reference in csproj file find the following line and replace the version number then restore the packages.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Comment: When i try to do Install Microsoft.Extensions.Logging -Version 2.2.0, it gives the error message  'Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from 3.1.0 to 
2.2.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.'